# Android Studio Project says project is already on GitHub despite the fact I deleted repository.

Tags: android, git, github, android-studio

I deleted the project from GitHub and want to re-share (create new repository) it via Android Studio but it still thinks I have it up on GitHub. Is there a way to reset this?

Comment: Do you still have the `.git` folder in your project? That means it is still a Git repository. If you want to push your changes to a new repository you need to change your remote.

Comment: point `git remote origin` to new repository and check.

Answer (score 21):

Open the /.git/config file and delete the lines:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/githubaccountname/MyProject.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Then open Android Studio and you will now be able to run the 'Share project on GitHub' without getting an error that it is already shared on github.

Comment: On Mac, how to open the "/.git/config" file to access that information? How to find the file, also?
Otherwise, this is my exact issue and you will have solved it!

Comment: The folder should be in the root of your project. The '.git' folder is a hidden folder so you will need to enable viewing hidden files and folders before you can see it.

Comment: That did the trick. I WARN viewers NOT TO look for this line in the git.config file, though, but SPECIFICALLY the .config file in the .git folder

Comment: i located the config file but how can i open it. It is not opening via NOTEPAD on windows any other software that i can use to open it .

Comment: @SagarDevanga The git config file should just be a text file so you should not have a problem opening it. On Windows this file may still have unix style line breaks which from memory are not handled by Notepad very well. Try opening it in a more advanced text editor such as Notepad++.

Comment: Hey Guys, I am getting the exception "Project is already on github".Where to find git config file in Windows 10 ?I cant find git config file in Windows 10.Please help me with this.

Answer (score 3):

I had a same problem, and I solved it in this way.

File->Setting->Version Control-> minus(remove) the Git path

Answer (score 3):

On the Top Menu, Click Git->Manage Remotes and click the delete button.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Remove all .git and .gitignore folders from your project directory
Step 2: VCS: Import into version control
Step 3: Create Git repository
Step 4: (Same dialog) Last option: Share project on Github
Step 5: Describe and Hit Share
Step 6: In next pop up : Hit -> Add (Will take some time).
Step 7 : Then Go to VCS in menu options at top on android studio -> Git -> Push

Then check your github account & See if its committed & pushed.
(-; Happy Coding :-)-----\